# Legal requirements for electronic flight bags like Foreflight or SkyDemon

Tags: easa-regulations, efb

I’m wondering what the legal requirements to use EFBs like ForeFlight or Skydemon or similar for primary flight planning and navigation. If I remember correctly, I once heard about requirements on battery percentage, backup device, external battery or similar.

In particular, I’m interested in the situation in Germany, but I’m happy to hear about differences to other countries (e.g. FAA vs. EASA) as well. I’d be happy about hints on where to find regulations like these as well.

Comment: These are portable devices that are not permanently mounted on the aircraft, so there are no regulatory requirements. It's up to you to make sure you have enough power, and if you run out, to be able to use your aircraft's normal navigational systems.

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/254/62) has some related information about the US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you actually have two questions here

> ...for primary flight planning

[EFB's with up to date charts](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_91_78.pdf) are [legal for planning and reference as covered in this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/254/do-pilots-using-an-electronic-flight-bag-need-to-carry-paper-charts).

Many EFB's (well at least foreflight that I know of) here in the US allow you to file flight plans, and receive briefs from a weather briefer right in the system.

> ...and navigation

EFB's are legal for navigation as you would use a map but they are *not* legal replacements for GPS/AHARS units despite the features they have. [Simply put they are not TSO'ed](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2020-138B.pdf) and not *legal* navigation instruments.

This is also [spelled out in the regs directly](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_91_78.pdf)

> The EFB system does not replace any system or equipment (e.g.
>   navigation, communication, or surveillance system) that is required by
>   14 CFR part 91.